# Telegram client на pythonanywhere с помощью telethon

Tags: python, telegram, pythonanywhere, telethon

Пытаюсь запустить telegram client на хостинге pythonanywhere на flask

Загрузил все необходимые библиотеки (см. [фото1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugHEM.png))

На [данном сайте](https://my.telegram.org/) создал api-приложение, получил его app_id и api_hash

Далее в самом коде flask приложения пишу так (для теста)

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    #------------------------Если ошибка при импорте-----------------------
    try:
        from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
    except Exception as e:
        return 'IMPORT ERROR: ' + str(e)
    #------------------------Обрабатываем----------------------------------

    api_id = API_ID_FROM_MY_TELEGRAM_ORG #Тут подставляю свое
    api_hash = API_HASH_CODE_FROM_MY_TELEGRAM_ORG #Тут подставляю свое

    #------------------------Если ошибка при создании объекта--------------
    try:
        client = TelegramClient('test_session', api_id, api_hash)
        return 'Succes!'
    except Exception as e:
        return 'OBJECT ERROR: ' + str(e)
    #------------------------Обрабатываем----------------------------------
```

При запуске и открытия приложения в браузере выводится следующая ошибка (в текстовом виде):

> OBJECT ERROR: database is locked

Данный текст соответствует последнему try/catch, соответственно ошибка возникает при попытке создать объект `client = TelegramClient('test_session', api_id, api_hash)`

Что это за ошибка и как в моем случае с ней бороться?

Comment: ты не вызвал метод start

Comment: @danilshik , а, то есть просто так создавать этот объект нельзя? я просто не шарю

Comment: я делал парсер с помощью этой библиотеки. Посмотри метод create client https://github.com/danilshik/telegram_parser/blob/master/telegram_new.py

Comment: @danilshik Ок, спасибо

Comment: @danilshik Проблема не исчезла

Comment: а ты точно api правильно ввел?

Comment: @danilshik ну копипаст

Comment: @danilshik может что pythonanywhere не позволяет?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел, в чем ошибка

Нельзя использовать каждый раз одно  и то же имя сессии в `client = TelegramClient('test_session', api_id, api_hash)`